# AttributeError: 'KeyboardEvent' object has no attribute 'click_loop'

Tags: python, kivy

Я создал легкую программу с помощью библиотеки kivy. Я пытаюсь вызвать цикл, через функцию, при нажатии клавишы, но у меня вылетает ошибка:

```
 AttributeError: 'KeyboardEvent' object has no attribute 'click_loop'
```

Вот мой код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock
loop=None
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout(size=(1000, 1000))
        button=Button(text='Start',on_press=self.start_tr,pos_hint={'center_x': .4, 'center_y': .4},size_hint=(.13, .13))
        button2 = Button(text='Stop', on_press=self.stop_tr,pos_hint={'center_x': .6, 'center_y': .4},size_hint=(.13, .13))
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(button2)
        return layout

    def click_loop(self,*args):
        print(1)
        #pyautogui.click(pyautogui.position())
    def start_tr(self,*args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.click_loop, 1)
    def stop_tr(self,*args):
        Clock.unschedule(self.click_loop)
    keyboard.on_press_key('y', start_tr)
    keyboard.on_press_key('x', stop_tr)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: А как вы думаете, что будет передано в `start_tr` в качестве первого аргумента т.е. `self` при вызове коллбэком после `keyboard.on_press_key('y', start_tr)`? Правильно - `KeyboardEvent` будет передано. Экземпляра класса `MainApp` в `self` не будет, ему там неоткуда взяться. Можете попробовать вместо `self` использовать `MainApp` в этих методах.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, но только я не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду. MainApp().start_tr() к сожалению не работает.

Comment: Я имею в виду внутри этих методов поменять `self.click_loop` -> `MainApp.click_loop`, попробуйте так для начала

Comment: @CrazyElf MainApp.start_tr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Скобки то откуда взялись?

Comment: @CrazyElf я то пишу без скобок, а оно вылетает со скобками